# Compare the object type of a class that inherits from a parent class but stored in vector of parent class

Tags: c++

I want to compare the object type of a child class which inherits from a parent class and is stored in a vector of parent class as below:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <typeinfo>
using namespace std;

class Agent{
public:
    Agent(string nam){ name = nam; }
    ~Agent();
protected:
    string name;
};

class Human :public Agent{
public:
    Human(string nam, int a):Agent(nam){ age = a; }
    ~Human();
protected:
    int age;
};

int main(){
    vector<Agent*> agents;
    Agent* agent=new Agent("ask");
    Human* human=new Human("ask2",18);
    Agent* agent2=new Human("AgentAsk",20);
    agents.push_back(agent);
    agents.push_back(human);
    agents.push_back(agent2);

    cout << (typeid(agents[1]) == typeid(Agent*)) << endl; /// True
    cout << (typeid(agents[1]) == typeid(Human*)) << endl; /// I expect it to be true but its false
    cout << (typeid(agents[1]) != typeid(Agent*)) << endl; /// False

    return 0;
}
```

I need help to obtain the proper result.
I searched for it but could not find a proper solution and explanation.
Please, try to explain your code as much as possible.

Comment: You don't want to compare them, you want to know the actual type of an instance. Right?

Comment: All elements of the vector `agents` are of type `Agents*` even if you push `Human*`

Comment: well yes i want to know the actual type of an instance.

Comment: @EissaN. can you solve it

Comment: @ASK Check my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37372355/2229960).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use type traits for your classes, but if you need a simple (quick and dirty, maybe) solution, you may do it as follows:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <typeinfo>
using namespace std;

class Agent{
public:
    static const string TYPE;
    explicit Agent(const string& nam) : name(nam) {}
    virtual ~Agent(){}

    virtual string type() const {
        return TYPE;
    }
protected:
    string name;
};

const string Agent::TYPE = "Agent";

class Human :public Agent {
public:
    static const string TYPE;
    Human(const string& nam, int a):Agent(nam), age(a) {}
    ~Human(){}

    virtual string type() const {
        return TYPE;
    }
protected:
    int age;
};

const string Human::TYPE = "Human";


int main(){
    vector<Agent*> agents;
    Agent* agent=new Agent("ask");
    Human* human=new Human("ask2",18);
    Agent* agent2=new Human("AgentAsk",20);
    agents.push_back(agent);
    agents.push_back(human);
    agents.push_back(agent2);

    for(auto agent : agents) {
        cout << agent->type() << " ";
        cout << boolalpha << (agent->type() == Agent::TYPE) << endl;
    }
    //free up memory allocated using new
    // or just use smart pointers

    return 0;
}
```

It's better to define an abstract class and move the abstraction (like type() method) up and other details down to the derived classes.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible approach to differentiate the types in a hierarchy at runtime (comments in the code, as requested by the OP):

```
#include<vector>
#include<cassert>

// This is a simple class that acts as a counter

struct Cnt {
    static int cnt;
};

int Cnt::cnt = 0;

// A template class helps us to differentiate
// the types and to give them a set of  values
// that identify the actual types at runtime

template<typename T>
struct Type: private Cnt {
    static const int type;
};

template<typename T>
const int Type<T>::type = Cnt::cnt++;

// The Agent offers a virtual method that
// returns a numeric identifier of the type.
// The above mentioned classes are used
// to generate an unique value for this type.

class Agent {
public:
    virtual int type() const {
        return Type<Agent>::type;
    }
};

// If you want Human to have its own
// numeric identifier, you can simply override
// the inherited method and return a different
// type.
// Using the Type class is still the right
// solution. It assures that the returned type 
// won't collide with the ones generated so
// far.

class Human: public Agent {
public:
    int type() const override {
         return Type<Human>::type;
    }
};

int main() {
    std::vector<Agent*> vec;
    vec.push_back(new Agent);
    vec.push_back(new Human);
    assert(vec[0]->type() == Type<Agent>::type);
    assert(vec[0]->type() != Type<Human>::type);
    assert(vec[1]->type() == Type<Human>::type);
    assert(vec[1]->type() != Type<Agent>::type);
}
```

It's pretty invasive, but this way you can also decide not to give a different type to a child if you want.

A note on `typeid`.
From [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid) you can find that:

> There is no guarantee that the same `std::type_info` instance will be referred to by all evaluations of the typeid expression on the same type

You wouldn't have had guarantees even if working with different types. Anyway, you are using the `typeof` operator each time on the same type.

Comment: @ASK Yeah, turn `struct Agent` to `class Agent`, add a `public` specifier and have a try for yourself. It works. Do you want me to change them in the example? Done.

Answer (score -2):

You created a vector of `Agent*`, so `(typeid(agents[1]) == typeid(Human*))` is false because `agents[1]` is an `Agent`, not a `Human`.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all. The OP is asking for a working solution.